# When is the String object created?

Tags: java, string

I am in the confusion that when is the String object created?
I mean at the time of identification process by a compiler where the compiler identifies each statement in a java class for binding
OR at the time of execution by jvm, where the jvm executes each statement in the java class based on the  binding.

Comment: It is created at execution/runtime. At compile time everything is converted to byte code and checked for any compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

No objects are instantiated at compile time.  This is impossible, regardless of the type.

Compiling a java class converts it into byte code, this byte code is executed within the JVM and this is where your objects are created in the heap.

Comment: And String literals (`"..."`) are stored in the constant pool of a .class file as UTF-8 bytes, and the class loader moves them to be shared (makes or takes a String), so "abc" in one class == "abc" in another.

Comment: @StuPointerException.. observe the simple code below as: if(boolean Exp1){ String someStr = "FirstStrObj"+someVar1;}else{ String someStr = "FirstStrObj"+someVar2;} then the doubt is how many times the string object "FirstStrObj" is created?

Comment: @Ahmed Shareef - The short answer is once.  However, compiler optimisations are very clever and will merge Strings if it can!

Comment: Thank you..! then do you recommend that I can have a String constant as String FIRST_OBJ = "FirstStrObj", and I can apply it in the if-else block OR i can continue with the previous code with out creating the String constant?

Comment: I would continue with the code as it is, the compiler will be in a better position to know how to optimise it if it thinks it can.

Answer (score 0):

String s1 = "iByteCode";

How this works?

■    JVM checks the String constant pool first and if the string does not exist, it creates a new   String object “iByteCode” and a reference is maintained in the pool. The variable ‘s1′ also refers the same object.

■  This statement creates one String object “iByteCode”.